# Bridging library File in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Does It work when we bridge the objective c library files in swift project? I tried, but I got the compiler error which says that files doesn't exist?

Comment: yes, it works . Make sure you include all required objective c file(.m and .h) files  into your project

Comment: thanks for reply.... hmm ok i will look to it..

Comment: You might want to have Xcode generate the file for you.  To do so, add a .m objective-C file to your project (you can delete it later).  Xcode should ask you if it should create the bridging header file for you.

Comment: refre this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: actually i tried the NWPusher .... the library are in the objective c ... those files are there in swift ?

Comment: swift is Mix and match  language you can use NWPusher in  swift

Comment: yet to  start the coding part.... i am just added the objective c files in swift using bridging ... in that itself i got the error ?